# optimizing select * on queries that is called multiple times

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, ubuntu, query-optimization

I have a table called order_list, in which it holds 700k entries.. continuously growing. In my show processlist in my sql i can see the following:

```
mysql> show processlist;
+-----+-------------+-----------+------+---------+------+-------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id  | User        | Host      | db   | Command | Time | State             | Info                                                                                        |
+-----+-------------+-----------+------+---------+------+-------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   2 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   13 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|   3 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   13 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|   5 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   13 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|   6 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   13 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|   7 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   13 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|   9 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   13 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  10 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   13 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  11 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   13 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  12 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   13 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  13 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   13 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  14 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   13 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  15 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   13 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  17 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   13 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  18 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   13 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  19 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   12 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  20 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   12 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  21 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   12 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  22 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   12 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  23 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   12 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  24 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   12 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  26 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   12 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  27 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   12 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  29 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   12 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  30 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   12 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  31 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   12 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  32 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   12 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  33 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   12 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  35 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   12 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  36 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   12 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  38 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   12 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  39 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   12 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  41 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   12 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  42 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   12 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  43 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   12 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  45 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   12 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  46 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   12 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  47 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   12 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  48 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   12 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  49 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   12 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  50 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   12 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  51 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   12 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  52 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   12 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  53 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   12 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  54 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   12 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  55 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   12 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  56 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   12 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  57 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   12 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  58 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   12 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  59 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   12 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  60 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   12 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  61 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   12 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  62 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   11 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  64 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   11 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  65 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   11 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  67 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   11 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  68 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   11 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  69 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   11 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  70 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   11 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  72 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   11 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  74 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   11 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  75 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   11 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  76 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   11 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  78 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   11 | Sending data      | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  79 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   11 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  80 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   11 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  81 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   11 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  82 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   11 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  83 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   11 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  84 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   11 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  85 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   11 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  86 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   11 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  87 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   11 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  88 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   11 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  89 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   11 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  90 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   11 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  91 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   11 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  94 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   11 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  96 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   11 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  97 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   11 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
|  99 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   11 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
| 100 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   11 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
| 101 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   11 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
| 102 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   11 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
| 103 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   10 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
| 105 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   10 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
| 106 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   10 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
| 107 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   10 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
| 108 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   10 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
| 109 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   10 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
| 110 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   10 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
| 111 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   10 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
| 112 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   10 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
| 113 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   10 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
| 114 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   10 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
| 115 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   10 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
| 116 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   10 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
| 117 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   10 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
| 118 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   10 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
| 120 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   10 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
| 121 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   10 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
| 122 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |   10 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
| 123 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |    9 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
| 124 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |    9 | Sending data      | SELECT `id`
FROM `order_list`
WHERE `user_id` = '32605'
AND DATE(created_at) = '2023-11-24' |
| 125 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |    9 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
| 126 | root        | localhost | smm  | Query   |    0 | starting          | show processlist                                                                            |
| 127 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |    9 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
| 128 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |    9 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
| 129 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |    8 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
| 130 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |    8 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
| 132 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |    6 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
| 133 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |    6 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
| 134 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |    5 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
| 135 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |    5 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
| 142 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |    3 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
| 143 | alex | localhost | smm  | Query   |    2 | Sending to client | SELECT *
FROM `order_list`                                                                  |
+-----+-------------+-----------+------+---------+------+-------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

now I am not sure which part in my application or function is making these call.. im suspicious that i might got DDoS attack as my web usually doesn't have these many traffic. I am kinda clueless on where to start in fixing this.. because of this my website can't be opened as the query is taking 100% of the resources of the machine.. increasing RAM and CPU did not help at all.

any thoughts or idea on how to start and fix this ? i've added cloudfront to my website just recently, but that did not fix the issue. in the access log all i am seeing is just a bunch of access to my homepage.. in which the homepage did not have any code querying for `SELECT * FROM order_list`

Comment: Have you tried to find the offending query by [profiling your application](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/profiling.html)?

Comment: In addition to profiling as mentioned above, are you also logging your traffic ? Maybe you could find a correlation between all the processes that have been opened, and traffic on your website.

Comment: You did not tell us much about your application. But it seems likely you have a [findAll](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/models/model.html#findall) without a where, and it's getting used in every page view. *Something* in your code is asking the database for every row in your table.

Comment: If your site isn't usable, then I'd just break it some more to see what's causing it. Turn on error reporting and then rename the table.

Comment: I'd start by finding out which client is using `alex@localhost` as its MySQL user. Is this your application? It seems odd to use a personal name as the credential, instead of some non-personal "app" user. If it's not your application, then figure out who it is. It could narrow down your search for the offending code (or person, if it's not code). You do know it's on the same server as the database, because it's `@localhost`. Is your app on the same server as the database?

Comment: @adit           You may find SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; is slightly more useful than SHOW PROCESSLIST;

Comment: Due to the low ID numbers in your SHOW PROCESSLIST, I would guess someone has modified your my.cnf [mysqld] section to include init_file with information to cause this query to run - forever.  A low-life could do this to you.  Also, check init_connect for similar bad intentions.  Consider in your cnf GENERAL_LOG=ON and be sure to turn it OFF, within 1 MINUTE of startup to avoid filling your storage media.  From MySQL Command Prompt,  SET GLOBAL general_log=0;  to turn OFF the general log and view your general log for detailed clues of startup processing.